# Continuous action of topological group and embedding

Tags: topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group act continuously on a topological space $X$.
Why the continuity of the action of $G$ on $X$ implies that $G$ embedded as
topological group in $S_{X}$. Here $S_{X}$ is the symetric group on $X$ i.e
the group of all self bijection on $X$ equipped with the pointwise topology.

Why the map $G\longrightarrow S_{X}$ is injective if the action of G on X is
continuous? Also, why this map is an homeomorphism?

Thank for any help.

Comment: An action for which $G \to S_X$ is injective is called [effective or faithful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Types_of_actions). You can let each element of $G$ act as the identity without that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way an action $\alpha : G \times X \to X$ is defined.

For a topological group, the group operation must be continuous. We define $\phi : G \to S_X$, where $\phi : g \mapsto \alpha_g$, by $\alpha_g(x) := \alpha(g,x)$ for all $g \in G$ and $x \in X$. Since $\alpha$ is a group action, we have $\alpha(g,\alpha(h,x)) = \alpha(gh,x)$ for all $g,h \in G$ and $x \in X$. Hence $\alpha_g \circ \alpha_h \equiv \alpha_{gh}$.

This tells us that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism.